# How to simplify $\frac{10+5y-2x}{30-2y+5x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I wanted to find out whether this algebraic fraction could be simplified further:

$$\frac{10+5y-2x}{30-2y+5x}$$

Comment: That looks clearer and simpler so, no unless there is more info.... like $\frac yx = z$ where $z$ is another variable

Comment: Where is this problem from? You should add some more details. However it seems to come from a differential equation which is reducible to homogeneous form.

Comment: Nope its pre-calculus @HarishChandraRajpoot

Comment: @Jasser: Can you give some more details if you don't mind? I mean what is the actual problem?

Comment: I meant the tag algebra-precalculus which would imply that it has not come from a differential equation @HarishChandraRajpoot

Answer (score 0):

Its just $\frac{2(5+y)+3y-2x}{30-5y+3y+5x}=\frac{2(5+y)+3(y+x)-5x}{3(10+y)+5(x-y)}$ but i dont see any reason why you want yo simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

No. There are obviously no factors in the numerator or denominator that can be factored out. Sometimes you can write the numerator as a constant times the denominator plus some simpler expression, but that is not the case here.